# How test if varnish is working (HIT or MISS)

Tags: nginx, port, varnish

I added in varnish file "default.vcl" a code for check if Varnish cache is working but I get a Transfer-Encoding "Chunked" and I cant see if Cache is working displaying HIT or MISS. I follow [next tutorial](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/varnish-wordpress-docker-container) and I believe have some port in nginx blocking his right function.
Code added within of "sub vcl_deliver":

```
if (obj.hits > 0) {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
} else {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
}
```

My settings:
Apache 2.4.6 port by default 7080

etc/nginx/nginx.conf without port by default (without port added)

etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf > server listen port MyIP:80 (default)

Varnish port 80 to external 32780 (Added from plesk)

etc/varnish/default.vcl: In host my IP and in port 7080

How can delete "Transfer-Encoding Chunked" and remplace it for "X-Cache MISS or HIT" to show in headers ?

Best regards